# Setting GridView width wrap_content

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, android-wrap-content

I am trying to use a gridView for a game with different board sizes. I sets the number of columns programmatically for the GridView, each column got an fixed size button inside it.The GridView width is set to "wrap_content" in the xml. However - The gridView is always spread as "match_parent" to the entire screen. Here hows it look:

[image]

[image]

This is mine GridView xml (It in a constrain layout). I already tried to add weight or wrap it with linear layout. I added :        android:gravity="center" and 
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
In addition I tried changing the stretchMode but it just got the columns to be with a huge spacing between each other, or got them to be rectangle when I really want to keep them squre.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:columnWidth="64dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:stretchMode="none"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"></GridView>
```

I couldn't find any working solution online,
Hope you can help, Thanks !